# zsh alias not recognising. Getting command not found error

Tags: shell, zsh, alias, zshrc

```
> ~ % alias ll="ls -l"
> ~ % alias
ll='ls -l'
run-help=man
which-command=whence
> ~ % ll
zsh: command not found: ll
```

Any idea why? It was working fine earlier, I was cleaning up some zsh scripts to reduce shell prompt loading time. And I ended up with an issue. I have tried single quote, double quote.

Comment: Did you really enter those three commands in this order, in the same shell? It works for me. What happens if you provide a different name? I.e. `alias foo='ls -l'`, and then in the **next** line, `foo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used fzf. I only use Ctrl+R key bindings and I removed other key bindings in the file. As part of it I have removed below if block https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/6e3a2fe0bf5d53434b41e868c501d9f63c6328aa/shell/key-bindings.zsh#L19.

That caused this issue. Still I didn't find exactly which line and why. I will check and update it here. For now this area was the cause and it got fixed